# averaging over 3rd dim, within a cell array, as efficiently as possible

Tags: matlab

I haven't found a good solution for this problem, which takes forever and seems to be mainly due to storage of the data in a cell array (as far as I see).

I process movie data in this format:

```
[data{1:4}] = deal(int16(randi([0 255],200,400,100))); %200px, 200px, 100 frames, 4 similar movies
```

Where data represents 4 different, but similar movies, in a `cell array`. Now I would like to take the average of the 4 variables data{1:4}, frame by frame. This is what I came up with:

```
for frame = 1:size(data{ind},3)
  tmp = zeros(200,400,'int16');
  for ind = 1:4
    tmp = tmp + data{ind}(:,:,frame);
  end
  data_avg(:,:,frame) = tmp./4;
end
```

is there a more efficient (faster performing, without doubling the RAM usage) way to do this (I haven't found any)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the fastest approach will be to do:

```
data_avg= (data{1}+data{2}+data{3}+data{4})/4;
```

no need for a for loop.

This is slower:  `mean(double(cat(4,data{:})),4);` because matlabs mean has an overhead inefficiency. your for loop is in between.

Comment: I don't think `mean` has that much of an overhead, but the `cat` certainly is expensive... it needs to copy all the data over into a new, gigantic array.

Comment: check and see for yourself : )

Comment: is this really equivalent to going through every frame? I'll test! RAM restrictions, i.e. duplicating the variable using `mean`, is also a substantially limiting factor here. Can this be written so it fits for any number of `data` lengths, i.e. dynamically? I wish `plus(data{:})` would work, but alas, no...

Comment: isequal() says reports true for the result, this is orders of magnitudes faster. thank you

Comment: i see what you mean by `plus(data{:})`, you can solve it by just adding a separate function that will do this, it rather straight forward.

Comment: I'll test whether that will duplicate the ram, that could be an issue

Comment: what I meant is that you can create a `sum_cell`  function, that does what I wrote in a loop fashion, where you loop on `1:numel(data)` for example: `sum_cell=zeros(size(data{1}),class(data{1}));
for n=1:numel(data)
    sum_cell=sum_cell+data{n};
end`